# Can comments be added to mocha.opts?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm, mocha.js

How can I add a comment to mocha.opts?

```
js
test
--recursive
--reporter spec
--require ./test/test.bootstrap
--require ./test/server.bootstrap
--slow 200
--delay
```

How do I comment out the last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of May 2018, Mocha added support for comments.

Anything that starts with a hash character (`#`) will be treated as a comment in the "mocha.opts" file. (See `mocha/bin/options.js` [cd3e1b3 commit](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/commit/cd3e1b39f61ca6f2b87cdff9bf0d529705505170) in the mochajs repository)

Comment: At the time of writing, there's a comment confirming this above `parseMochaOpts` in [lib/cli/options.js](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/cli/options.js#L91).

Answer (score 4):

I went through the trouble of trying every comment style I could think of.Then I looked in the source code:

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/bin/options.js

Mocha takes that option file and treats it like a bunch of command line switches/arguments.

So, no, there's no way to put a comment in there. Add the feature and open a pull request. See what the community thinks.

Comment: There seems to be a sneaky way, by prefixing an option that you want to "comment out" with an additional hyphen (`---slow 200`).

Comment: I just tried that with recursive and got  unknown option `---recursive'

Comment: Which version of Mocha? I'm using 3.5.0.

Comment: Oh hang on, that happens for me as well if I don't pass a test path/file argument (either in the options file, or on the command line).

Comment: ha 2.4.5 :).  I guess it it depends on the version!

Comment: As suggested, added a PR here https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/2961

Comment: I think you are going to need to write some tests.

Comment: you cant make me!